# Questions in user-specific search shown as having accepted answer, while not having one

Tags: bug, design, android-app

While going over my posts here to see which of my bug reports could be closed with a new version of the app, I saw this:

[image]

I know for certain I haven't accepted the answer for the second question yet (because I haven't got a chance to confirm it). The third question doesn't have an upvoted answer.

I know that questions with upvoted answers count as answered, but I'd always taken the green-filled `A` to mean that it had an accepted answer.

And I can reproduce while searching for another user's questions, searching specifically for posts without accepted answers:

[image]

Note the zero-answers post marked as having an accepted answer - it's actually closed as a duplicate and has no answers.

I don't think this is intentional, since the main site feeds still use the green-filled `A` only for posts with accepted answers:

[image]

The question with four answers has upvoted answers, and it is not shown as having an accepted answer.

---

- App: 1.0.84 beta
- Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1